Can "Nazi stormtroopers" refer to uniformed military, or is that incorrect usage?
My understanding is that the "storm troopers" were specialized infantry in World War 1 (not Nazis), and a paramilitary group in the years leading up to World War 2 (yes, very much Nazis).
In Archer, Season 9, Episode 7, (set in 1938) the term "Nazi stormtrooper" is used over and over to refer to what appeared to be soldiers of the German army (see image below).
Is this a correct usage for the term?


Does this Wikipedia page answer your question?

Fundamentally this is a language question. Words and terms mean what they are understood to mean. So if that was commonly said, and the listeners correctly understood what was meant when it was said, then mission accomplished. After all, who were those soldiers ultimately taking their orders from, if you follow the chain of command up to the political levels? Nazis. Those were soldiers being directed by the Nazis. Soldiers of the Nazis. Nazi soldiers. Its a way of putting the blame on the political philosophy, not the German people.

There is an anti-pattern; almost every question that begins < Can X be termed Y...> self-answers.  The person writing the question just termed X as Y.  The solution is to revise the question and ask something more precise. "What is the definition of stormtrooper?" (which will trigger the basic research anti-pattern),  Question needs improvement before re-open

Honestly, the variant of that kind of question I'd consider valid would be more along the lines of "What did {term x} usually mean during {period y} when spoken by {cultural group z}?" You can't just ask what something means, because the very question presumes a single definite linguistic authority which does not exist. But we can certainly talk about the history of it.

This question seems to have been treated somewhat harshly.  First of, no, the wikipedia page does not address the subject very well, being limited to the SA.  The given answer by om is actually quite thorough covering the types of various S-units the Germans and Nazis might be referring to.  Having said that, anything related to Nazis is by its very nature contentious and basing the Q on, and posting a screenshot from, a comedy show wasn't the best choice that could have been made to frame the Q.

@ItalianPhilosopher Thank you. I felt badly after reading the comments here. It was a genuine question, which I thought had an angle worth discussing.

@Deane Well, Nazi-related subjects are touchy by nature and sometimes the community may misjudge posts.  You are the only person who knows in what sense you asked it, of course.  But a much younger remembers me being somewhat confused about the SS vs SA vs Sturmxxx verbiage.  Finding om's answer would have greatly clarified things for me, so upvote for the Q.

Infantry were Sturmtruppen (storm troopers), the party thugs were the Sturnabteilung (storm detachment).
Sturm literally means storm, and in a military context it means assault. This can refer both to troops in a Sturmbatallion or Sturmkompanie and to regular troops employing the tactics of these specialized battalions.
Nazi propaganda was highlighting the heritage of these military units, and appropriating the name for their own purposes.

During the trench warfare of WWI, tactics developed which were called Stoßtruppen. Sturmbataillone were especially trained in these tactics and taught them to regular infantry.
Stoßtruppen had a mixture of riflemen, grenadiers, machine gunners, and other heavy infantry weapons at the platoon or squad level. That was unusual at the start of WWI, but somewhat common for infantry before and during WWII (see e.g. the development and issue of the general-purpose machine gun in Germany). So the average German infantry platoon of 1939 had elements of the equipment and training of the Stoßtruppen of 1916.
Between the wars, the Nazi party formed the Sturmabteilung (SA) for use in the civil war where they gained power. The SA was temporarily turned into "auxiliary police" after they gained power and issued with "official" armbands, they already had truncheons and some guns.
The SA was greatly diminished, but not disbanded, during the Röhm purge in 1934.
The infamous Schutzstaffel (SS) was originally part of the SA, but it overshadowed the SA after 1934. The SS formed combat units which were technically not part of the German Army, as well as camp guard/murder units. (The non-camp SS units committed plenty of atrocities, too).

